# invisible button that works android xml

Tags: android, button, visibility

I want to set a button to be invisible because there will be a picture in front of it to act like the button. Do you guys know how to set this up in the xml?

thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you set that picture as background to that button?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best thing you can do is to use directly an `ImageView` instead of a `Button`, setting always a `OnClickListener` on it in order to catch click action. Maybe you can also add a proper [selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) in order to get a visual feedback on the pressed/unpressed state.